# Is it possible to make Storybook.js working with very large auto-generated Typescript files (>200 classes)?

Tags: typescript, storybook, nswag, angular-storybook

I'm having an issue with `Storybook.js` that I'm using with another library called [NSwag TypeScriptClientGenerator](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/TypeScriptClientGenerator).

So i'm not sure if it is a bug or if I have a bad configuration but here are the details.

**TLDR version:**

NSwag generates a huge API client file with hundred of classes. Then `Storybook.js` crashes when trying to load all those classes

**More details:**

I'm working on an angular project that consumes a REST API. This API has a lot of endpoints and i'm using `NSwag` in order to have compilation checks on this API calls.

`NSwag` read the API description (openAPI/swagger) and then generates a typescript file that describes all API endpoints and all parameters and return types.

This result in a very big typescript file with a lot of interfaces/classes/functions. There are more than 30k generated lines of code and file is `2mo`.

Now comes Storybook.js. When I run `npm run storybook` the tool starts by creating the `documentation.json` file.

This file contains 1 json entry per class/interface and for each of those entries there is a `sourceCode` member that contains the file source code.

Problem is that the `sourceCode` member contains ALL the file code, not just the class or interface code.

As the file contains hundred of classes and interfaces then ALL those classes are described in `documentation.json` file, and ALL of those entries contains a `sourceCode` member that contains ALL the 30k lines of codes (in the screenshot, line `601` is `1,599,000` characters -> there are hundred of lines like this on the rest of the file).

[image: Picture showing the sourceCode fill with all the API code]

The resulting `documentation.json` file is more than `700mo`. And the result is that storybook crashes while trying to parse that huge file.

Do you have any tips to fix that problem?

**Question:**

Is it possible to tell `Storybook.js` to ignore this file? If yes: are there some cons doing that?

Or is it possible to tell `Storybook.js` to not create this `sourceCode` entry?

Or maybe is it possible to ask NSwag Typescript Generator to generate one file per class?

Comment: I saw your comment on https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1398. It sounds like a good feature to have. We have a 20k generated file with all the interfaces and TS  code that makes the http calls.